# polynomial can have more than n roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I'm studying polynomials.

Here's a theorem that is presented in the book regarding zeros of polynomials:

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n > 0$, then there exist n complex numbers $c_1, c_2, ... , c_n$ such that

$$f(x) = a (x-c_1)(x-c_2) \dotsm (x-c_n) $$

where $a$ is the coefficient of $f(x)$ and each number $c_j$ is a zero of $f(x)$

The corollary to this theorem presented in the books states that a polynomial of degree $n>0$ has at most $n$ different complex zeros.

Given this theorem and corallary, here is the question from the book that I am having trouble understanding:

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials of degree not greater than $n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Show that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal in value for more than n distinct values of $x$, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are identical; that is, coefficients of like powers are the same.

(*Hint*: Write

$$ f(x) = a_nx^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dotsm + a_1x + a_0$$
$$ g(x) = b_nx^n +b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dotsm + b_1x + b_0$$

and consider

$$ h(x) = f(x)-g(x) = (a_n-b_n)x^n +(a_{n-1}-b_{n-1})x^{n-1} + \dotsm + (a_1-b_1)x + (a_0-b_0)$$

)

Then we are to show that $h(x)$ has more than $n$ distinct zeros and conclude that $a_i = b_i$ for all $i$.

So my question is, how can I show that a polynomial has more than $n$ distinct zeros, when the corollary to the theorem I presented above states that a polynomial with positive degree $n$ can have at MOST $n$ distinct complex zeros?

Comment: You've almost said the answer yourself...! This is a proof contradicting the assumption that the polynomial has degree $n>0$. What possible polynomials remain?

Comment: am i correct in thinking that a contradiction of the statement $n>0$ in the context of this problem would mean that $n$ could be an element in the set of integers less than or equal to $0$? but the problem says n is a positive integer? so i'm not sure I understand the contradiction.

Comment: @HumanityFirst The degree of $h(x)$ is not necessarily $n$, it's just $\le n$. In fact, the argument proves that it cannot be $n$, and by the same argument it cannot be $n-1, n-2, \dots,1$ either. At that point, there is only one possibility left.

Comment: @dxiv when you say 'the argument proves it', to which argument are you referring? that the degree of $h(x)$ is $\leq n$? so does this mean its degree must be $0$? so the polynomial $h(x)$ is just a constant?

Comment: @HumanityFirst "*we are to show that $h(x)$ has more than $n$ distinct zeros*" $-$ This implies that $\deg h \ne n$. $\;$ "*its degree must be $0$*" $-$ Right. $\;$ "*$h(x)$  is just a constant*" $-$ Not just any constant, since it takes the value $0$ several times, so $h(x)$ must be the identically zero polynomial.

Comment: ah ok -- i guess it's still a little confusing for me -- because if $h(x)$ is supposed to have more than $n$ distinct zeros, that makes me think its degree would be greater than $n$, but that notion directly conflicts with the question, which says it can have a degree no greater than $n$. I guess that's why it must necessarily be the 'identically zero polynomial' you mentioned.  i think i have a much better understanding now thanks to you and @GregMartin for helping me think this through.